# Yii2 Authentication not working as expected

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on a micro service. It has basically login and registration. I followed the Yii2 official guide. But now i am facing an issue. When i try to send request to the endpoints which are protected ( Only users with access_token can make request ) It works but very strange it checks all the rows in the database and if access_token is matches any rows in the database then it allows the request. But what i want - I am trying to get users information, if i pass the token i want only the information which belongs to current user ( Whose token is in request ) .

I am doing this in my UserController -

```
public function behaviors() {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    ];
    $behaviors['authenticator']['only'] = ['view'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

And in  `User` model have implemented this method -

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}
```

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: `HttpBearerAuth` only authenticate user. It doesn't filter returned data. You need to implement data filtering in your action.

Answer (score 0):

If the `access_token` in the request matches the `access_token` value for any of the users in the database, then, like you say, the authentication filter will forward the request to the corresponding action on your controller.

At this point the application `user` component points to the user that was found, you can use the user's component `id` to recover the record matching the request's user from the database.

```
// Get the user record
$current_user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

// Do something with the user record
return [
    'username' => $current_user->username,
    'last_update' => $current_user->updated_at
    ...
];
```

Comment: You can use `Yii::$app->user->identity` instead of `User::findOne(Yii::$app->user->id);` it will return object implementing `IdentityInterface` loaded in `yii\web\User` component. This will save you the extra query for loading the user by id.

Comment: @MichalHynčica nice, I didn't know that, thank you, I will update the answer

Comment: You've made a mistake in your edit. It's `Yii::$app->user->identity` not `Yii::$app->user->id->identity`